# Bitbucket and Gitlab search all public repositories

Tags: api, gitlab, repository, bitbucket, public

I would like to search all public `Bitbucket` and `Gitlab` repositories.

At the moment I could only find a `bitbucket` api that gives me repositories, but I can't make a query, like `q=nameRepository`

`Bitbucket`: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-get), Bitbucket allows filtering on repositories, but given the enforced limitations, it doesn't seem to be possible to use it for searching all the public repositories.

- You need to follow [filter syntax](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#filtering), and specify the property you want to filter upon, for example: `?q=full_name~foo` to search property `full_name` for string containing `foo`.
- However, when using the `q` parameter, you need to also specify the `role` parameter, which will limit the search only to the repositories the user has some role in.
- Since you need to specify the role, you also must provide an access token, so you cannot access the API anonymously.

In conclusion, Bitbucket explicitly limits searching through public repositories with API. The official way to search public repos is via this web interface: https://bitbucket.org/repo/all

---

Things are simpler with GitLab, use the [/projects endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) with `search` parameter. You need to [authenticate](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html#authentication) either with OAuth2 access token, or personal access token:

```
GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?search=foo
Authorization: Bearer <access or personal access token>
```